# Model class doesn't find in KMM proyect which use Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, kmm

I was developing an App which make use of the Kotlin Multiplatform plugin, and I try to use the Navigation component, to navigate between the diferent fragments of my app.

My problem comes due to the complex structure of KMM proyect compare with regular Android Proyect.

When I try to run my proyect , the diferents class of Navigation component which are generated, doesn't find by my FragmentArgs class, which make use of it.

That is in KMM the User interfaces is separate in a diferent folder, and the business logic is another class, as the database too.

In this capture it can see the regular structure of KMM proyec:

[image]

So the error, generate in my DetailFragmentArgs is this:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    private final UnplashPhoto photo = null;
                  ^
  symbol:   class UnplashPhoto
```

The code of my nav.graph.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/HomeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/HomeFragment"
        android:name="com.jshvarts.kmp.android.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigate_from_home_to_detail"
            app:destination="@id/DetailFragment">
            <argument
                android:name="photo"
                app:argType="shared.src.commonMain.kotlin.com.jshvarts.kmp.model.UnplashPhoto"/>
        </action>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/DetailFragment"
        android:name="com.jshvarts.kmp.android.detail.DetailFragment"
        android:label="DetailFragment" >
        <argument
            android:name="photo"
            app:argType="shared.src.commonMain.kotlin.com.jshvarts.kmp.model.UnplashPhoto"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I try to some path, but doesn't work: from repository, from content root, and source root.

If you are more experienced in KMM plugin and deal with this problem somepoint, you help is welcome !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

in your build.gradle add the following

```
plugins {
   id ("kotlin-android-extensions")
}

kotlin {
    android{
        androidExtensions {
            isExperimental = true
        }
    }
```

.....

Add the following in your commonMain

```
expect interface Parcelable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMultiplatform::class)
@OptionalExpectation
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
expect annotation class Parcelize()
```

and in your androidMain

```
actual typealias Parcelable = android.os.Parcelable
actual typealias Parcelize = kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

Then annotate your model with `Parcelize` and implement `Parcelable`